# Segmentation fault in stack in push Function C language

Tags: c, linux, stack, segmentation-fault, towers-of-hanoi

I had faced problem with it when i start the program it crashed at function Full and push line 70 and 78 (Linux). I try to fix it but I always crash at the same place.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #define SIZE 64

   struct stack{
      int TowerTop;
      int Elem[SIZE];
   };

   /* Forward Declarations */                    
   void push(int Elem, struct stack *x);
   int  create (struct stack *x);
   int  full(const struct stack *x);
   void pop(struct stack *x);
   int lolol(struct stack *x,struct stack *x2,struct stack *x3,int a);

   void main() {
      int j;
      int a = 5; 

      //scanf("%d",&a);

      struct stack Tower1;
      struct stack Tower2;
      struct stack Tower3;

      create(&Tower1);
      create(&Tower2);
      create(&Tower3);

      for(int i=0; i<=SIZE-1; i++) {
          Tower1.Elem[i]=0;
          Tower2.Elem[i]=0;
          Tower3.Elem[i]=0; 
      }

      for(int i=0; i<=a; i++){
          Tower1.Elem[i]=i+1;
      }

      // Display initial tower setup
      for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
         printf("%d %7d %7d\n",Tower1.Elem[i],Tower2.Elem[i],Tower3.Elem[i]);
      }

      lolol(&Tower1,&Tower2,&Tower3,a);

      // Display Tower after move made by lolol
      printf("%d\n", j);
      for(int i=0; i<a; i++) {
         printf("%d %7d %7d\n",Tower1.Elem[i],Tower2.Elem[i],Tower3.Elem[i]);
      }
    }

    int lolol(struct stack *x,struct stack *x2,struct stack *x3,int a) {
       if(a == 1) {
          printf("\n Disk 1 move to");
          push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2->Elem[x2->TowerTop]); j++;
          pop(x->Elem[x->TowerTop]);
          return 0; 
       }

       lolol(x, x3, x2, a-1);
       push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2->Elem[x2->TowerTop]); j++;
       pop(x->Elem[x->TowerTop]);
       lolol(x3, x2, x, a-1);
      }

      int create(struct stack *x) {
         x->TowerTop = -1;
      }

      int full(const struct stack *x) {
          if (x->TowerTop == SIZE-1) {
             return 1;
          } else {
             return 0;
          } 
       }

       void push(int Elem, struct stack *x){
          if(full(x)) {
             printf("Stack is full"); 
          } else {
             x->TowerTop++;
             x->Elem[x->TowerTop]=Elem;
          }
       }

       void pop( struct stack *x) {
          if(x->TowerTop== -1) {
             printf("Empty");
          } else {
             x->TowerTop--;
          }
       }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you looked up what causes a Segfault?

Comment: Nice indentations.

Comment: Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Note: homework questions have additional requirements to be on-topic. Your teacher expects you to solve it yourself. Programming includes debugging. Get used to it.

Comment: @tkausl: Remeber beginners take such comment serious (I hope you are kidding, are you?). OP: learn about coding styles and use a common one! Don't get creative with formatting, therre is a reason only 2/3 styles are.well established, your's is none of them!

Comment: Your program has function parameters mis-matched with calling arguments, and functions with no value returned. Please enable all compiler warnings (it gave me 10) and follow them up.

Comment: Please can you give any tips what should i fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will debug your code together. But first, I'll tell you more on how to ask questions on forums (thus on StackOverflow).

First there is no 'as fast as possible' since we're all here to help. We'll try our best and it may or may not be on time. Then please read your message again with your code and ask yourself, is this readable? I really do hope your code does not look the same way in your file and you just failed somehow the copy/paste because this code is quite unreadable.

## First step: Change the code to make it readable.

I will skip the verbosity of this step but basically it is indenting, adding spaces when needed etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 64

struct stack
{
  int TowerTop;
  int Elem[SIZE];
};

void push(int Elem, struct stack *x);
void pop(struct stack *x);
int create (struct stack *x);
int full(const struct stack *x);
int lolol(struct stack *x, struct stack *x2, struct stack *x3, int a);

int a;
int j;

void main()
{

  //scanf("%d", &a);
  a = 5;
  struct stack Tower1;
  struct stack Tower2;
  struct stack Tower3;
  create(&Tower1);
  create(&Tower2);
  create(&Tower3);

  for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
      Tower1.Elem[i] = 0;
      Tower2.Elem[i] = 0;
      Tower3.Elem[i] = 0;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
    {
      Tower1.Elem[i] = i + 1;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
      printf("%d %7d %7d\n", Tower1.Elem[i], Tower2.Elem[i], Tower3.Elem[i]);
    }

   lolol(&Tower1, &Tower2, &Tower3, a);

   printf("%d\n", j);

   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
      printf("%d %7d %7d\n", Tower1.Elem[i], Tower2.Elem[i], Tower3.Elem[i]);
    }
}

int lolol(struct stack *x, struct stack *x2, struct stack *x3, int a)
{
  if (a == 1)
    {
      printf("\n Disk 1 move to");
      push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2->Elem[x2->TowerTop]);
      j++;
      pop(x->Elem[x->TowerTop]);
      return 0;
    }
  lolol(x, x3, x2, a - 1);
  push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2->Elem[x2->TowerTop]);
  j++;
  pop(x->Elem[x->TowerTop]);
  lolol(x3, x2, x, a - 1);
}

int create(struct stack *x)
{
  x->TowerTop = -1;
}

int full(const struct stack *x)
{
  if (x->TowerTop == SIZE-1)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  else
    {
      return 0;
    }
}

void push(int Elem, struct stack *x)
{
  if (full(x))
    {
      printf("Stack is full");
    }
  else
    {
      x->TowerTop++;
      x->Elem[x->TowerTop] = Elem;
    }
}

void pop(struct stack *x)
{
  if (x->TowerTop == -1)
    {
      printf("Empty");
    }
  else
    {
      x->TowerTop--;
    }
}
```

Please not that I did not change any logic or types or whatever.

## Second step: reading code.

Actually I'll probably come back to this later but I took a quick read and there is some basic stuff that need to be said. The `main` function shall always returns an `int`. According to the C standard, you can only declare the `main` function with two ways: `int main(void)` (takes no parameters) or `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` (takes command line parameters).

Then, you must know that the two variables `a` and `j` are globals to the file. That mean you can access them everywhere in the same source file. Sounds good, doesn't work. You should NEVER EVER do global variables, unless you have NO OTHER CHOICE (e.g using `sigaction`). In your case, they are really not needed.

Lastly, COMMENTS. Please, commend your code. While most of it is understandable easily here, the function `lolol` (that name does NOT make sense at all btw) is doing something I don't understand when taking a quick look at the code.

## Third step: compiling

`gcc file.c` => 4 warnings. Unless you know what you're doing and are an experienced C programmer - which you are not (yet!) you shouldn't have any warnings when compiling. Furthermore, you should compile with the `-Wall -Wextra` switches. That will throw more warnings but allow you to catch bugs before they even exists.

So we will fix the warnings:

- `warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]`. Alright, let's switch that. `void main()` becomes `int main(void)`, as I said earlier.
- `file.c:64:34: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘push’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` => Alright, here you're using the `push` function which I'm assuming you wrote. However, this function expects an `int` as it's first parameter and a `struct stack *` as it's 
  second parameter when you're passing it an `int`. Let's fix that: `push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2->Elem[x2->TowerTop]);` becomes `push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2);`, since you're pushing `x->Elem[x->TowerTop]` on the top of the `x2` stack.
- Same thing for the next three warnings, being the `pop` line 66, the `push` line 70, and the `pop` line 72.
- Next two warnings are the same: `file.c:74:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` => I'm still not sure what `lolol` is meant to do, so I'll just add a `return 0` at the end of it, and switch the `create` function to `void` type.

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 64

struct stack
{
  int TowerTop;
  int Elem[SIZE];
};

void push(int Elem, struct stack *x);
void pop(struct stack *x);
void create (struct stack *x);
int full(const struct stack *x);
int lolol(struct stack *x, struct stack *x2, struct stack *x3, int a);

int a;
int j;

int main(void)
{

  //scanf("%d", &a);
  a = 5;
  struct stack Tower1;
  struct stack Tower2;
  struct stack Tower3;
  create(&Tower1);
  create(&Tower2);
  create(&Tower3);

  for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
      Tower1.Elem[i] = 0;
      Tower2.Elem[i] = 0;
      Tower3.Elem[i] = 0;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
    {
      Tower1.Elem[i] = i + 1;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
      printf("%d %7d %7d\n", Tower1.Elem[i], Tower2.Elem[i], Tower3.Elem[i]);
    }

   lolol(&Tower1, &Tower2, &Tower3, a);

   printf("%d\n", j);

   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
      printf("%d %7d %7d\n", Tower1.Elem[i], Tower2.Elem[i], Tower3.Elem[i]);
    }
}

int lolol(struct stack *x, struct stack *x2, struct stack *x3, int a)
{
  if (a == 1)
    {
      printf("\n Disk 1 move to");
      push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2);
      j++;
      pop(x);
      return 0;
    }
  lolol(x, x3, x2, a - 1);
  push(x->Elem[x->TowerTop], x2);
  j++;
  pop(x);
  lolol(x3, x2, x, a - 1);
  return 0;
}

void create(struct stack *x)
{
  x->TowerTop = -1;
}

int full(const struct stack *x)
{
  if (x->TowerTop == SIZE-1)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  else
    {
      return 0;
    }
}

void push(int Elem, struct stack *x)
{
  if (full(x))
    {
      printf("Stack is full");
    }
  else
    {
      x->TowerTop++;
      x->Elem[x->TowerTop] = Elem;
    }
}

void pop(struct stack *x)
{
  if (x->TowerTop == -1)
    {
      printf("Empty");
    }
  else
    {
      x->TowerTop--;
    }
}
```

Compiling and running without SIGSEGV.

## Last step: Going further

I'll talk about topics more advanced, but it could be useful to you. First, get more informations about stack and how they works because I'm not sure you've completely understood it.

Also, to debug your programs you can use `valgrind`, it is a memory checker tool that is very useful and always comes in a handy. To use it, add the flag `-g` when compiling.

I suggest looking into `gdb` as well, the GNU Linux debugger. Very powerful.

The function `full` can be changed to a simple `return x->TowerTop == SIZE - 1`. It avoids branching and hence will run faster.

And that's all folks. Still not sure what your code should do but you only asked about how to fix your segfault. Now please just remember. **Do not let any warnings when compiling.**

Thank you.

Comment: thank you very much. i'm sorry for my words. English is not my first laguage trying to get used to it

Comment: Don't worry it's alright. I just hope you understand your mistakes and become a better programmer. :)

Comment: @MatthewDarens Please accept Doe's answer if it solves your question